# Intersection of algebraic curves in the complex projective plane

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, coordinate-systems, projective-geometry, projective-space

I am trying to find the number of points of intersection of the affine plane curves $y=x^{2}$ and $y=x^{2}+1$.

I have homogenised to find $$YZ=X^{2}$$ $$YZ=X^{2}+Z^{2}$$ and deduced there is a point of intersection at $(0:1:0)$. Setting $Y=1$ I get the affine curves $z=x^{2}$ and $z=x^{2}+z^{2}$. According to Bezout there should be 4(?) points of intersection when considering over the field of complex numbers. Obviously $(0,0)$ is on both curves. I am however struggling to find the other 3.

Comment: How do $y = x^{2}$ and $y = x^{2}+1$ possibly have any intersections? $(0,0)$ is not on the second curve.

Comment: Notice that your affine points should all have $Z=1$.

Comment: There is only one point, $(0,1,0)$, but its multiplicity is $4$. In Bezout's theorem you count every point as many times as its multiplicity. There are no complex solutions in this case.